# I want to add new row in my table but I want to do mathematical operation using column names (SQL)

Tags: sql

i have a table like this

| 2001 | 2002 | 2003 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125.000 | 313.000 | 515.00 |

I want to add annual percentage growths as rows

Comment: in your table year columns always the same? I mean do you always have 3 columns?

Comment: actually ı have 6 columns as a year

Comment: and columns can be added in future? if yes, then better to have structure as @TimBiegeleisen suggests

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also show the results that you want.

Comment: Please avoid dramatically changing your question after others have already answered it.  If you need help with months level date data, then ask a _new_ question.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your table structure to this:

```
year | val
2001 | 125.000
2002 | 313.000
2003 | 515.00
```

Then use the `LAG` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT
    year,
    val,
    100.0*(val - LAG(val) OVER (ORDER BY year)) / LAG(val) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR) AS pct_growth
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY year;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I can solve the problem. If I want to see 2001- January / 2002 January growths ,How should ı?

Comment: @OsmanBüyükyılmaz . . . Your sample data and question make no mention of months, so your comment doesn't apply to this question.